# How to list all possible moves in connect four game

Tags: java, bitmap, bit-manipulation, artificial-intelligence, bitboard

I am making an AI following this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-the-perfect-connect-four-ai-bot-c165115557b0). The basic idea is using bitboards to make a extremely fast protocol for making modifications to the board and permutating through possible game outcomes.

But the article is written in python and I had trouble following the initial bitboard setup. I went to the [github readme](https://github.com/denkspuren/BitboardC4/blob/master/BitboardDesign.md) they reference in hopes to develop the framework for my AI and then worry about alpha-beta pruning and the machine learning later.  Essentially I got past the methods for `checkWin`, `makeMove`, and `undoMove` and estabilished the required fields for the height of columns, moves, the count of moves, and the array of long variables representing the bitboards for the players.

But I am currently stuck at the generate moves method because it tries to initialize all the values at the top of the bitboard outside of the columns. But in java I can't seem to do this: it just gives me the error this literal type is out of range for type long. Additionally seeing as moves is a `int[]` I'm not sure how to use `moves.push(col)`. Because that gives the error cannot invoke `push(int)`. Below you will find the broken `listMoves` method and my current code and I would be very appreciative if anyone could tell me some things I might be doing wrong in my code and or how to fix the `listMoves` method. Cheers!

```
   private int[] listMoves() {
        int[] moves;
        long TOP = 1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000L;
        for(int col = 0; col <= 6; col++) {
            if ((TOP & (1L << height[col])) == 0) moves.push(col);
        }
        return moves;
    }
```

My code

```
 public class EConnectFour {
    private int[] height = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private int[] moves = new int[42]; // add size 
    private int counter = 0;

    private long[] bitBoard = new long[2];



    public static void main(String[] args) {



    }

    private char[][] getGameState() {
        // add code to get current gamestate 
        return new char[0][0];
    }


    private boolean isWin(long bitBoard) {
        int[] directions = {1, 7, 6, 8};
        long bb;
        for(int direction : directions) {
            bb = bitBoard & (bitBoard >> direction);
            if ((bb & (bb >> (2 * direction))) != 0) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void makeMove(int column) {
        long move = 1L << height[column]++;
        bitBoard[counter & 1] ^= move; 
        moves[counter++] = column;  
    }

    private void undoMove() {
        int column = moves[--counter];
        long move = 1L << --height[column];
        bitBoard[counter & 1] ^= move;
    }
}
```

Comment: Write `0b1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000L` for a binary `long` literal. It's in range. You cannot `push` to an array in Java.